# Quick drop shadow css question for ie8 not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, dropshadow

Just a quick simple question, this css code will not work in ie8 for a drop shadow, any ideas why it wouldn't work?

```
/* Drop shadow */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
-o-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

Comment: I have never seen CSS like this. Can't you use shadow images instead?

Comment: @Midas it is CSS3 and one of its benefits is that you do not have to use images any more :-)

Comment: I find `-ms-filter` to be redundant and unnecessary for IE8.  You found the code here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is an IE8 bug but if you add a `background-color` it [seems to work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/S7yqr/1/).

In Chrome, removing the `background-color` leaves the drop shadow, but in IE8 the text inherits the drop shadow and looks awful. If you have a solid background you could match the background on the elements you want the drop shadow on. Unfortunately `transparent` results in the same problem in IE8.

Comment: you can easily get rid if it by using http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: It's not a bug.  Without the background color, `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow()` creates a shadow for the text only.  `box-shadow` is a CSS3 property for box shadows.  So to get the same effect in IE, you have to specify a box.  This was the correct solution to the problem though. +1

Comment: Funny, I was looking for a solution to a similar problem and *removing* `background-color` is what solved it for me. Gotta love IE.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a width on the element with the shadow filter fixed a similar issue for me.